# Missing Branch coverage in enum class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk, test-coverage

I have enum class

```
enum class Type(val type: String) {
    ONE("one"),
    TWO("two"),
    THREE("three");

    companion object {
        private val mapByType = Type.values().associateBy(Type::type)
        fun fromType(type: String) = mapByType[type.lowercase()] ?: ONE
    }
}
```

I create a function like this

```
internal fun handleTypeAction(movieModel: MovieModel) {
    when (movieModel.type) {
        Type.ONE -> xyzfunction()
        Type.TWO -> xyzfunction()
        Type.THREE -> xyzfunction()
    }
}
```

I know there is 3 branch coverage. I made a test case like this

```
    @Test
    fun `handleTypeAction - WHEN type is ONE THEN should call xyzfunction`() {
        val mockMovieModel = mockk<MovieModel>()
        every { mockMovieModel.type } returns Type.ONE
        subject.handleTypeAction(mockMovieModel)
        verify { subject. xyzfunction() }
    }


    @Test
    fun `handleTypeAction - WHEN type is TWO THEN should call xyzfunction`() {
        val mockMovieModel = mockk<MovieModel>()
        every { mockMovieModel.type } returns Type.TWO
        subject.handleTypeAction(mockMovieModel)
        verify { subject. xyzfunction() }
    }
    
    @Test
    fun `handleTypeAction - WHEN type is THREE THEN should call xyzfunction`() {
        val mockMovieModel = mockk<MovieModel>()
        every { mockMovieModel.type } returns Type.THREE
        subject.handleTypeAction(mockMovieModel)
        verify { subject. xyzfunction() }
    }
```

So how I missing branch coverage in here? What is the 4 branch coverage in here?

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
@Keep
@Parcelize
data class MovieModel(
    val actionTitle: String = "",
    val type: Type = Type.ONE,
) : Parcelable
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that's Jacoco, but I think the answer would be the same if you used other tools. Code coverage is computed based on the bytecode rather than on the source code. If you analyse the bytecode you'll see that enums are converted to a `int[]` (based on their `ordinal`) and in fact the compiler generates 4 branches inside `handleTypeAction`:

```
TABLESWITCH
  1: L3
  2: L4
  3: L5
  default: L6
```

Jacoco can't figure out that the `default` branch is actually impossible, so it highlights it as a missed branch.

It's interesting thought that if you force the compiler to check for exhaustiveness (example below), coverage reaches 100%. I'll check why that's the case and update this answer.

Example:

```
fun handleTypeAction(movieModel: MovieModel) {
    val x = when (movieModel.type) {
        Type.ONE -> doSomething()
        Type.TWO -> doSomething()
        Type.THREE -> doSomething()
    }
}
```

## Update

The behaviour seems to be caused by a potential bug in Jacoco.
That's because if an exhaustive `when` is used, the following bytecode is generated:

```
tableswitch   { // 1 to 3
                 1: 52
                 2: 67
                 3: 82
           default: 97
      }
... // ignoring all matched branches
97: new           #55                 // class kotlin/NoWhenBranchMatchedException
100: dup
101: invokespecial #59                 // Method kotlin/NoWhenBranchMatchedException."<init>":()V
104: athrow
105: astore_1
```

If a regular `when` is used, the following bytecode gets generated instead:

```
tableswitch   { // 1 to 3
                 1: 40
                 2: 52
                 3: 64
           default: 73
      }
... // ignoring all matched branches
73: return
```

Note that in the first case, it throws an exception when no branch is matched, while in the second case it just continues the execution (by returning to the caller, since I didn't add anything after the `when` instruction).

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/blob/master/org.jacoco.core/src/org/jacoco/core/internal/analysis/filter/KotlinWhenFilter.java) of Jacoco, it's apparent how it intentionally strips out the extra bytecode that deals with the `default` branch (since the compiler ensures it's unreachable), which explains why using the exhaustive `when` expression leads to full coverage.

Now, technically your code is already exhaustive because you're covering all (interestingly, the IDE knows that because it raises a warning if you add an `else` branch, but the compiler doesn't say anything), but Jacoco doesn't know that and hence considers the `default` branch as not covered. You can either raise it as a bug to the Jacoco team (not sure how easy it is to perform this exhaustiveness check on Jacoco's end), or use this knowledge to add a dummy `else` branch that throws a `NoWhenBranchMatchedException` specifically (not that any other exception won't be stripped out by Jacoco, so it will be raised as a missed branch), like this:

```
when (type) {
    Type.ONE -> ...
    Type.TWO -> ...
    Type.THREE -> ...
    else -> throw NoWhenBranchMatchedException() // the compiler will raise a warning saying it's redundant
}
```

I

Comment: How can i check my compile code?

Comment: you can check the bytecode by executing `javap -v SomeJavaFile.class` (note is requires the compiled file, i.e. the `.class`) or in Intellij you can go to `Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode`

Comment: @KotlinLearner I updated my answer with my recent findings

Answer (score 0):

> What is the 4 branch coverage in here?

Probably: `null`

I haven't used Jacoco so I don't know if it has specific support for Kotlin.
However if it's just looking at the Bytecode it probably can't tell that the `movieModel` variable is non-nullable. Hence its reporting that the variable could be null and hence isn't handled.

Comment: I added my model. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be the case that it doesn't detect that there is no else state in your when expression?

```
internal fun handleTypeAction(movieModel: MovieModel) {
    when (movieModel.type) {
        Type.ONE -> xyzfunction()
        Type.TWO -> xyzfunction()
        Type.THREE -> xyzfunction()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException(") // Here
    }
}
```

You can try also covering this case.